# Javascript toggle not working for element's child and child's sibling

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

In a menu I am trying to control class toggles at different item levels with JavaScript. As the menu is dynamically generated I cannot add individual ids to the menu items or elements (partly because the menu could appear twice on a page and then there would be duplicated ids).

What I have done is create data-toggle value automatically based on the item's level. Hopefully, this will stop a standard dropdown-toggle in an element from toggling its parent instead of its child.

However, I am trying to do this with vanilla JavaScript and NO jQuery and I understand that JavaScript needs an ID as a starting point. I also understand that toggling first adds a class and then removes it.

I have created a very simple menu, CSS and JS to demonstrate what I am trying to do:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("LI>button");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].addEventListener("click", toggle);
   function toggle() {
   var y = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("LI>button").nextSibling;
    y[0].classList.toggle("dropdown1");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
<style>
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropdown0 {
 display: none;
 }
.dropdown1 {
 display: block;
 }
</style>
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item single">Single Level 1
    <a class="nav-link one" href="/">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item single parent">Parent
    <a class="nav-link one">PARENT</a><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <ul class="nav-child dropdown0 dropdown-menu">
        <li class="nav-item single">Single Level 2
        <a class="nav-link one" href="/">LEVEL 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For the first 'get' line I have also tried this instead (based on examples from other posts here):

```
var x = document.getElementById("menucontent>LI>button");
```

At at the end I have tried this for the var y:

```
var y = document.getElementById("menucontent").getElementsByTagName("LI>UL");
```

But neither work.

My JS is very basic and I have been trying to sort this out for nearly a week and I don't have much hair left, so any help would be very welcome. Thanks.

EDIT: removed follow-on query. Will open new request.

Comment: *I understand that Javascript needs an ID as a starting point.* <-- Not at all. In fact, IDs should be avoided because they create brittle code that doesn't scale well. There are numerous ways to locate the correct element without an `id`.

Comment: *I also understand that toggling first adds a class and then removes it.* <-- Only if the class isn't there to begin with. If it's already there, then first it is removed and then added back. You are entirely in control.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus. I've tried without the id but every example I've found explaining how to toggle classes is illustrated using the id.

Comment: Tutorials often show code examples that are the easiest to understand, but not necessarily the best choice for all intents and purposes. All that you really have to have to use the toggling feature is `someElementReferenceNoMatterHowYouGotIt.classList.toggle("className")`. If you look at [the documentation for `.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), you see it says: ***Using classList is a convenient alternative to accessing an element's list of classes as a space-delimited string via element.className.*** ...

Comment: ...It doesn't say anything about how you should go about getting the element reference. You'll find this concept all throughout, not only JavaScript, but in programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) requires that you pass a single string which
  is the `id` of an element, but you've passed
  `"menucontent>LI>button"`, which is a CSS selector and not the `id`
  of an element.
- [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) requires that you pass a single string
  which is the name of a tag (i.e. `input`, `div`, `p`, etc.). You are
  passing: `"LI>button"`, which is not the name of a single tag.

If you wish to pass a CSS selector, use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to return the first element that matches your selector or [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return a collection of all the matching elements.

The following code works no matter how many levels you have as long as the HTML is structured identically in each level.

- It doesn't require any of the elements to have `id`s.
- There's just one event handler.
- There are no loops.
- The function that does the work is just a single line of code inside of an `if` branch.

If you'd like a level to start out hidden, just add the `hidden` class to that `ul` in the HTML.

```js
// Don't set up events in the HTML with onXyz attributes.
// Separate your JavaScript from your HTML. Also, just 
// set up one event handler on the ancestor of the whole
// list and handle any clicks within it there.
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
  // All clicks anywhere within the "test" element will be handled here
  // You can find out which specific element triggered the event with
  // event.target. Then, you can access other elements relative to the
  // event.target. 
  
  // First, make sure it was a button that was clicked
  if(event.target.type === "button"){
    // Here, we look for the next sibling element
    // and toggle its use of the "hidden" class.
    event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* This one class will take care of both being 
   visible and not being visible. When the class
   is applied, the element will not be visible.
   When the class is removed, it will go back 
   to being visible. There is no need to make a
   second class. */
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item single">Single Level 1
      <a class="nav-link one" href="/">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item single parent">Parent
      <a class="nav-link one">PARENT</a>
      <button type="button">Try it</button>
      <ul class="nav-child dropdown-menu">
          <li class="nav-item single">Single Level 2
            <a class="nav-link one" href="/">LEVEL 2</a>
          <button type="button">Try it</button>
            <ul class="nav-child dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-item single">Single Level 3
                  <a class="nav-link one" href="/">LEVEL 3</a>
                <button type="button">Try it</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. If you can bear it, I've added another query to the bottom of my original post.

Comment: @Gillian You really should post that as a new question.

Comment: You are quite right and I thought the same overnight. I have removed it from here. Thx.